# How to click on an image (not button) using Selenium

Tags: selenium

Before this, I have automated a login into the website howe page. I was stuck trying to make it so that it clicks on the image to navigate to another webpage.

```
shop_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/footer/div/div[2]/a/img")

shop_button.click()
```

[This is the code for the image hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BLM6.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below xpath

```
//p[text()='Shop']//preceding-sibling::img
```

this should locate the `img` node, however `p tag` which has `Shop` as a text has to be `unique` in nature.

If it's unique, you can click on it like:

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Shop']//preceding-sibling::img").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Shop']//preceding-sibling::img"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

PS: `time.sleep(5)` is just for visualization purpose, you should not use it ideally if code 2 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect to another webpage by clicking on a image. According to the code snippet, I can see that Image tag is inside the  tag, you can click on that.
Can you try this ?

`shop_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/footer/div/div[2]/a")`

`shop_button.click()`

Do let me know if this works.

Comment: Inside the <a> tag***

Comment: No it’s still showing the error